# How we can detect an empty thumbnail with api's youtube?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to detect an empty thumbnail using api's youtube. Here is what I mean by an empty image https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D0YTglgckWs/hqdefault.jpg to avoid it. There is any solution to do that please ?
By the way, I used getImageSize($url) to return the resolution. And it works perfectly on my case ! But it needs much time to respond, especially I need to verify 20 thumbnails at the same time ! 
So hope I was clear !

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to be more specific about the problem you are having so that we can help.

Comment: You could definitely just detect if that string or index exists. But as pointed out by @Starkeen we would really appreciate a code you have tried and build upon that code.

Comment: it's clear, I want to avoid such empty thumbnail on my blog ! youtube api don't provide the way to do that.

Comment: @user117088 Could you provide the JSON file that youtube responds with please? That will really help with building an example code.

Answer (score 1):

suppose the `$video_youtube_link` is your youtube link, so you can detect this by this script:

```
parse_str( parse_url($video_youtube_link, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $arr_of_vars );
//print_r($arr_of_vars); exit;
$video_id_on_youtube = '';
if(isset( $arr_of_vars['v'])) {
$video_id_on_youtube = $arr_of_vars['v'];
}
$image_link ='http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$video_id_on_youtube.'/0.jpg';
$video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_id_on_youtube;
```

where `$image_link` is the thumbnail and `$video_link` is video link

Comment: I know how to retrieve the thumbnail's video. What I am asking, is how to detect that thumbnail's type https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D0YTglgckWs/hqdefault.jpg  . thank you !